# Finding `datalist` by Name in Form?

Tags: javascript, html

Given a form:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('f').elements['a']);
console.log(document.getElementById('f').elements['b']);
```

```html
<form id='f'>
  <input name='b' list='list' type='text'/>
  <datalist name='a' id='list' />
  <input name='btn' type='button' value='go'/>
</form>
```

Why does my attempt to get the `datalist` by name `a` return `undefined`? However, when I search by name `b`, it succeeds?

Comment: Because `datalist` is not present in `elements` property?

Comment: Ah - you've answered my immediate question - thanks! I should've asked, why does it not show up in the `elements` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.children`. The control for the element would be `<input>` element having attribute `list="list"`, at `<form>` submission the key, value pair would be name `b`, value selected `<option>` child element of `<datalist>` element, select an `<option>` submit `<form>` and see `Network` tab for resulting query string parameters

```
b:123
btn:go
```

or

```
b:456
btn:go
```

Note `<datalist>` element is not self closing, closing `</datalist>` tag is required for valid HTML.

```js
onload = () => {
  console.log(document.getElementById('f').children["a"]);
  console.log(document.getElementById('f').elements['b']);
}
```

```html
<form id='f'>
  <input name='b' list='list' type='text' />
  <datalist name='a' id='list'>
    <option value="123">123</option>
    <option value="456">456</option>
  </datalist>
  <input name='btn' type='submit' value='go' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#htmlformcontrolscollection-0 elements that can be in `elements` property [are](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#category-listed):

```
button, fieldset, input, keygen, object, output, select, textarea
```

So, if you want `<datalist>` to be considered as `element` - you can refer to W3C)

Answer (score 1):

The `elements`property only contains form controls. Since datalist is not a form control, it is not included. For more information see [MDN docs on HTMLFormElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement) and the [associated collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection).